# How to make datalist NOT apear on the source code

Tags: php, html

I have a long list of words and i don't want it to appear when i view the source code. how can i do that using php, or even html

this is an example of the code i have

```
<label for="country_name">Country : </label><input id="country_name" name="country_name" type="text" list="country" />
<datalist id="country">
   <option value="Afghanistan">
   <option value="Albania">       
   <option value="Algeria">      << there's a lot of words here
   <option value="Andorra">
   <option value="Angola">   
</datalist>
```

Comment: Insert after DOM is loaded using Javascript. They'll still be visible using "element inspectors" though, just not in "View Source"

Comment: Can you explain why your want to hide certain source code? Because as it stands, your question indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of the technology.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some simple JavaScript in a different file. This is kind of a bodge fix, but it will make it so that none of the country names show up in the "view source" window, however, they will show up if you inspect the country datalist.

Put this in a JS file:

```
var countryList=[
"Afghanistan",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
...
];

function addCountries(){
    for(var i=0;i<countryList.length;i++){
        var elem=document.createElement("option");
        elem.setAttribute("value",countryList[i]);
        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML+=elem;
    }
}
```

And change your country datalist to this:

```
<datalist id="country">
    <script type="text/javascript">addCountries();</script>
</datalist>
```